# C# iTunesLib com: AlbumArtist member not accessible with intellisense

Tags: c#, com, itunes, itunes-sdk

I am using the iTunesLib V1.13 in C#.
I can read the current playing track just fine together with its Artist, Album, TrackName, Duration, etc.. properties.
But I can't read the 'AlbumArtist' property. Even though it shows up while debugging:

[image]

But I can't seem to access it in code...

[image]

It also does not show up in the metadata of the interface IITTrack, but I don't understand why I see it when I debug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it by casting the track to a `dynamic` type in C#.

```
iTunesAppClass iTunesApp = new iTunesAppClass();
dynamic track = iTunesApp.CurrentTrack;
string albumArtist = track.AlbumArtist;
```